# Save position of Jquery draggable DIVs using php

Tags: php, jquery, html, draggable

There are a lot of solutions out there as to how to save the position of draggable DIVs but I haven't found any that will help with using a While loop in php.

I have a database of "needs" and I want to display all the "needs" that match the persons username and status=inprogress. This could be 1 need or 1,000,000 needs depending on if the criteria is met.

I want to save the position of the need (DIV) automatically when it's moved. Is this possible? I wanted to store the values in a database using SQL if I can.

Here the code I currently have that displays the "needs" (divs)

Header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <style>
  #set div { width: 90px; height: 90px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0; }
  #set { clear:both; float:left; width: 368px; height: 120px; }
  p { clear:both; margin:0; padding:1em 0; }
  </style>


<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#set div" ).draggable({ 
    stack: "#set div" 
  });
});


</script>
```

Body

```
<div id="set">

<?

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM needs WHERE (needsusername='$username' OR workerusername='$username') AND status='inprogress'");


while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$title = $rows['titleofneed'];
$status = $rows['status'];

echo "
<div class='ui-widget-content'>
$title<br>Status: $status<br>

</div>
";
}

?>
</div>
```

Insert Query

```
$x_coord=$_POST["x"];
$y_coord=$_POST["y"];
$needid=$_POST["need_id"];

    //Setup our Query
    $sql = "UPDATE coords SET x_pos=$x_coord, y_pos=$y_coord WHERE needid = '$needid'";

    //Execute our Query
    if (mysql_query($sql)) {
          echo "success $x_coord $y_coord $needid";
         }
        else {
        die("Error updating Coords :".mysql_error());   
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `stop` event of draggable to get noticed when an element has reached a new position. Then you just have to get the offset [as described in the docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-stop).

Assuming you have a setup like that:

```
<div id="set">
    <div data-need="1"></div>
     <div data-need="2"></div>
     <div data-need="3"></div>
     <div data-need="4"></div>
     <div data-need="5"></div>
</div>
```

I've used a data attribute to store the id of the "need", you can later on use that id to store the position of the "need" in the database.

Now as mentioned before, use the stop event to send an ajax call to the server with the id of the need and the x and y postion of it. Be aware hat this is the position of the screen so if you have different screen sizes you should probably use positions relative to a parent container with a desired position.

```
$(function() {
  $( "#set div" ).draggable({ 
    stack: "#set div",
      stop: function(event, ui) {
          var pos_x = ui.offset.left;
          var pos_y = ui.offset.top;
          var need = ui.helper.data("need");

          //Do the ajax call to the server
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "your_php_script.php",
              data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, need_id: need}
            }).done(function( msg ) {
              alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            }); 
      }
  });
});
```

This way every time a draggable element reaches a new positions e request will be sent to `your_php_script.php`. In that script you then only have to grab the post parameters and store them in the database.

There is [**a working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CAEV5/9/), of course the ajax request is not working but you can see whats going on in the console.

Comment: copy and pasted from fiddle and now the boxes don't move.  I see where you're going with it though.  You see any reason why the boxes won't move?

Comment: Not really because I don't know how your code exactly looks like now. jQuery and jQuery UI still included?

Comment: Also works on jsbin with exactly your code: http://jsbin.com/aqucud/2/edit. The only thing I don't have is your css file.

Comment: Got that to work.  what are the POST names for each data?  is it x, y, and need_id?  Having trouble putting the pos_x and pos_y and need_id into the sql table.

Comment: Yes you should be able to get it with `$_POST['x']`, `$_POST['y']` and `$_POST['need_id']`.

Comment: that's what I have.  for some reason every time I move a square it will put the x as 0 and it won't even put anything for the y, but the need_id is working.

Comment: the strange part is when I echo those values in the alert message I get back telling me if it was a success, those values are the correct values

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputation to do that

Comment: I've just got that message too... How does your insert query look like?

Comment: Are the needid, the x_pos and y_pos fields all defined as varchars?They should be integers and therefore you don't need `'`.

Comment: And of course remove the `AND` and use a comma: `x_pos = $x_coord, y_pos = $y_coord`

Comment: I made them integers and did as you said in the sql staement and still no good.  Figured it out though.  take the "_pos" out of the column name in the database so it's just "x" and "y".  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Got another question you might be able to answer.  Everything is working fine. The only issue is that whenever I place a block somewhere it gets the position of where it is on the page 

But when I go to call that x and y number back when I refresh the page it put it relative to the "wrapper" div I have it in.  Make sense?

Comment: Ok then before adding the position to the database remove the x and y position values of your wrapper div from the values so your values will be relative to your wrapper. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: well I think it's something deeper than that.  the link I show you doesn't even have a wrapper...yet when it's saved and you refresh it doesn't stay in the same spot.  Could it be because I'm trying to overlap the divs?  I want to overlap them sometimes.

Comment: fixed it by setting postion:relative to position:fixed thanks again.

Comment: No problem. Just in case you need it later. I've made a fiddle with positions relative to the wrapper `#set`: http://jsfiddle.net/CAEV5/14/