# Saving jQuery UI draggable value?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery-ui

I need help figuring out the best solution, I simply want to take jQuery UI draggable value and save it.

Im reading up on ajax, but I am not sure how to implement ajax and the PHP database (im using wordpress, It would be nice to just store the data in the wp database).

[Save position of Jquery draggable DIVs using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324557/save-position-of-jquery-draggable-divs-using-php) This seems to cover what I need, I am just not sure about ( url: "your_php_script.php",) "In that script you then only have to grab the post parameters and store them in the database." How do I write the post parameters? Could someone explain that?

Here is

```
     <?php

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM needs WHERE (needsusername='$username' OR      workerusername='$username') AND status='inprogress'");


      while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      $title = $rows['titleofneed'];
      $status = $rows['status'];

      echo "
      <div class='ui-widget-content'>
      $title<br>Status: $status<br>
      ";
     }

   ?>
```

Setup

```
    //Setup our Query
$sql = "UPDATE coords SET x_pos=$x_coord, y_pos=$y_coord WHERE needid = '$needid'";

//Execute our Query
if (mysql_query($sql)) {
      echo "success $x_coord $y_coord $needid";
     }
    else {
    die("Error updating Coords :".mysql_error());
```

}

the ajax

```
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "your_php_script.php",
          data: { x: pos_x, y: pos_y, need_id: need}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }); 

     $_POST['x'], $_POST['y'] and $_POST['need_id']
```

This code was copied from the link above, I am just trying to make sense of it and see if it does apply to my goal? I understand some parts, isnt $query specifying a table, then while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) is putting the data onto the table.. Im confused here in these parts, how would I write it to connect to my databse?

Here is the .draggable call

```
    $( ".ELEMENT" ).draggable({
    containment: '#_moon_static_bg_status',
});
```

Comment: where is your drag/drop javascript code

Comment: added.. you can see its bare

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what need_id is but it is probably something that you can get from a data attribute. The code below will send the new position of your element every time you stop dragging the element:

```
$( ".ELEMENT" ).draggable({
    containment: '#_moon_static_bg_status',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "your_php_script.php",
          data: { x: ui.position.left, y: ui.position:top, need_id: need}
        }).done(function( msg ) {
          alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
        }); 

    }
});
```

Comment: Ok how do I pass that into your_php_script how do I call the database and add it? Is the code above a good framework?

Comment: Sorry, I've wrote the worng input parameter in the callback function. You can get the values of x and y by $_POST['x'] and $_POST['y'] .You can just modify your script above. I suggest you use pdo or mysqli because the mysql_* will be deprecated. Also PDO and Mysqli have preparet queries wich will escape any illegal chars

Comment: ok cool, im still new to interacting with the database, so Im gonna have to figure out how I am going to write a script suited for my database, the code above is copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324557/save-position-of-jquery-draggable-divs-using-php